# How to find error message at storage/logs log files

Tags: php, laravel, debugging, laravel-5.8, logfile

I'm running a Laravel 5.8 project on live server and I had set the `APP_DEBUG=false`, and now I faced a **500 | Server Error** and then I tried looking at the `storage/logs` and opened the log file (there was only one log file) but couldn't find the error that appears on page when `APP_DEBUG` is set to `true`.

So I changed it back to `APP_DEBUG=true` and saw this:

`Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Shop\UserWalletTransaction' not found`

But it is not written in the log file. So the question is, how can I find the proper error message in the log file when `APP_DEBUG` is set to `false`?

Comment: Use error handler and send email when error occurs. This is the good approach.

Comment: Example :  Throwable $e
            $error['file']    = $e->getFile();
            $error['code']    = $e->getCode();
            $error['line']    = $e->getLine();
            $error['message'] = $e->getMessage();

Comment: make sure that your storage/ dir is writable

Comment: @SMI Can you explain more about it as answer or give me a like to readmore about it

Comment: @hassan It is writable

Comment: @nagidi recursively writable?

Comment: I don't get what u mean by recursively writable

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/errors#custom-http-error-pages @nagidi